# Synchronous clock between Server and Client

Tags: java, time, client

In my application I have a Server and x Clients. When a Client starts, he obtained the current System time from the Server. Every Client has to work with the Server time and can´t use his own System time.

**Now my Question:** What is the best way to run a clock on the Client that starts with the current Server time and run nearly synchronous to it without to receive the Server time every x seconds?

The goal is to display a **runing** clock with the Server time on the client.

The tolerance that the client clock may have is about 1second in 24hours.

In my solution I got a Timer that trigger every 500ms and count 500ms on the Server time when the Timer executes. But this is not a good solution :) because the Client clock differ from the Server time.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: What is the intent of this? Do you need to poll for time that often or would it be possible to rethink yuor solution and simply only get the time when you need it?

Comment: I'd rely on existing solutions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol (although that wouldn't *force* the client to use the server time...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a Solution that fits perfectly for my situation. 
Instead of using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, I'm using `System.nanoTime()`. 
`System.nanoTime()` is independent from the System clock.

When I receive the current Server time, I save additional the ns from the System. Then the current Server time will be calculated with the difference between the ns time from Server time receiving and the current nanoTime plus the Server time.

Example:

```
// The Client starts and receive the current Server time and the nanoTime
private long         serverTime = server.getCurrentTime();
private long         systemNano = System.nanoTime();

//To calculate the current Server time without a service call
                                                                        //ns-> ms
long currentServerTime = serverTime + ((System.nanoTime() - systemNano) / 1000000);
```

Thx

Answer (score 3):

You should almost certainly use an established clock synchronization method such as [the Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) rather than building your own custom solution.  It will provide you with better results than you will make yourself, and you have the added benefit that all your servers agree about what time it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to get the difference between the server time and the local time and use that for time calculations

- The client starts and gets the time from the server (I am going to assume use the current time in milliseconds but this can be adapted to whatever you are using)
- The client checks its current system time and saves the difference
- The difference can then always be applied to the current system time on the client to calculate the server time

Example:

```
long serverTime = 1328860926471l; // 2012/02/10 10:02, received from wherever
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // current client time
long difference = currentTime - serverTime;

// Server time can then me retrieved like this:
long currentServerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - difference;     
Date serverTimeDate = new Date(currentServerTime);
```

Obviously the difference must be saved the moment the server time is received.

Comment: What happend when the Client change his System time? Thats why i´m looking for a solution without using `System.currentTimeMillis()` on the Client.

Comment: Yeah this solution will give wrong result if user changes system time while running the program, it will need to check the current server time ever so often. Network Time Protocol will give you the best result assuming you are able to use it.

Comment: I don't think this works. It relies on the client clock to actually be correct, which is what the question is about. You only have one clock, the one on the server.